# while loop is not working in file copy

Tags: c, loops

Here I am trying copy content of `file1` to `file2` using this code

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){   
    FILE *fs,*ft;
    int ch;
    fs=fopen("C:\\Users\\BRAHMA JAISWAL\\Desktop\\a.txt","a+");
    if(fs==NULL){
        puts("Unable to open Source file");
        exit(1);
    }
    ft=fopen("C:\\Users\\BRAHMA JAISWAL\\Desktop\\b.txt","wb");
    if(ft==NULL)
    {
        puts("Unable to open TArget File");
       fclose(ft);
        exit(1);
    }

    puts("Enter anything which you want to write in source file:");
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    fprintf(fs,"%d",a);

    while(1)
    {
        ch=fgetc(fs);
        if(ch==EOF)break;
        fputc(ch,ft);
    }

    fclose(ft);
    fclose(fs);
    return 0;
}
```

It is not working(content of file1 isn't copied to file2) But when I remove this part of code then it's working properly.

```
puts("Enter anything which you want to write in a source file:");
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);
fprintf(fs,"%d",a);
```

can anyone tell the problem ?

Comment: You have to describle what you consider as "*not working*".

Comment: What do you mean by not working

Comment: Sounds like you fixed it yourself by removing the code. Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fprintf(fs,"%d",a);` is actually printing to your source file, not your target file.

And source file should probably be opened in `r` mode not `a+`.

Comment: but after fprintf(fs,"%d",a) I have used While loop for copying In  R mode copying was not working that's why I choose A+ mode

Comment: Because the file is opened in "append" (mode a+), after you have written once the file cursor is now positioned at the end of the file so reading it will give you nothing since there is nothing after the end. There isn't a distinct "read" and "write" cursor in C, just one for both.